# Where should I put my Testimonials page?

Tags: website-design, content

I'm building a website that will have a customer testimonials page. The site will have the following top-level categories:

```
    Services
    About
    Market Information
    News
    Events
    Contact
```

All content pages on this site will fall under one of these categories. I'm thinking that a testimonials page could fall under services or about, and I can think of reasons for and against each choice. But I'd like to hear any ideas, opinions or experiences anyone may have with this issue.

Comment: There is no correct answer here. It's going to entirely depend on your situation, target audience, CMS / template design etc. How important are the testimonals? If they're what 90% of your users come there for then it should be a whole new site section, but if they're only used by 5% of the audience then it can sit deeper in the site. Perhaps do some card sorting with your actual audience to determine where they would expect to find that content.

Comment: Thanks, but I knew that. I'd like to hear ideas and experiences without a situation or target audience in mind.

Answer (score 1):

It is really depending on how important you see the testimonials for the goal that you want to achieve.

Basecamp (https://basecamp.com) used to have it right as first point in their navigation so people have this social trust / assurance.

You can even put one or two on the homepage and then have a read more button that leads to  the own testimonials page.

Keep it simple.

Comment: *"Basecamp used to have it right as first point in their navigation"*. [Here is a screenshot of their current design where testimonials are lower down the page.](http://i.imgur.com/GRPc3Mt.jpg)